# Google detecta malware en mi Wordpress al pautar en Google Ads

Tags: wordpress

Hola tengo un inconveniente cuando realizo el proceso de pauta a mi stio,

Gooogle me indica que tengo **Malware** en mi sitio web, pero he realizado la comprobación con **Google Search Console**, **Google Safe Browsing** entre otros sitios en línea que ayuda a verificar Malware en los sitios web, pero no he tenido éxito verificando donde se encuentra alojado el Malware si es desde la base de datos o algún archivo en especifico.

He revisado la base de datos y archivos de mi Wordpress pero no he encontrado nada relevante, Google me adjunto un archivo con urls en donde me indica que esas urls tienen malware pero no pertenecen a mi sitio web tampoco a plugins que estén instalados actualmente.

**Esta es la url de pauta**: https://thepeoplecompany.net/gestion-administrativa-facility-management/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=Search&utm_campaign=Gestion%20Febererocon

**Acá pueden ver todos los links que google me manda y que dice que tengo infectados**: https://gist.github.com/Carlosvva/10ad721442847cec49885d9183dd0689

Si alguien conoce algún software para detectar esto o sabe como es que Google detecta este virus y pueda ayudarme a resolver este tema se los agradecería.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta puede o no caer en los motivos de cierre. Mientras tanto, una pregunta: por qué tu sitio es thepeoplecompany punto com y los recursos se cargan de otro dominio?

Comment: @Alfabravo mi dominio es thepeoplecompany.net y los links que adjunte en la hoja de Gits son los que Google me esta detectando con malware y ya he buscado en todo el sitio web código malicioso pero no he tenido éxito y no estoy cargando esos **.js** en mi sitio web, lo que quiero es alguna herramienta que me ayude a encontrar estos links o código que invoca a estos links

Comment: Herramienta no vas a recibir aquí porque no es el enfoque del sitio. Aquí se revisa código y errores en el código. Mi sugerencia personal es que montes el sitio de cero y con recursos controlados, porque adivinar qué script está corrupto es una pésima práctica de seguridad y tu servidor puede estar comprometido.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Alfabravo claro veré como solucionar ese tema montando todo de nuevo y siguiendo las mejores practicas para mantener el wordpress seguro, La herramienta la buscaba porque Google detecto malrware y yo con herramientas externas y de google hice un scan pero no tuve resultados y quería saber si alguien conocia como Google detectaba ese malware

Comment: Como comentario, Google tiene firmas de scripts que reconoce como malware. Así mismo, valida si hay XSS en los scripts de tu sitio o si está cargando recursos de sitios de terceros de forma insegura.